# Is it possible to set the max duration of voice record time using speech_recognition module in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I'm using the speech_recognition module in Python.  I have it use `adjust_for_ambient_noise()` before recording audio with `listen()`.  The problem is sometimes it just tries to record seemingly forever, and then when it finally finishes it eats bandwidth transfering the large audio file it recorded to Google for transcription.

Is there a way for me to specify a maximum record time of like 5 seconds?

Setting `timeout=5` is only the amount of time it will wait to detect a starting audio signal.

```
import speech_recognition


def listen(rec, mic):
  with mic as source:
    print('adjusting mic for ambient noise..')
    rec.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print('listening..')
    # timeout is not max record time but max time it will wait for audio to start
    audio = rec.listen(source, timeout=5)
    try:
      print('sending audio to google..')
      outputString = rec.recognize_google(audio).lower()
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
      print('google was not able to transcribe the audio')
      return None
    except speech_recognition.RequestError:
      print('google API unreachable')
      return None
    except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
      print('timout expired while waiting for audio command to start')
      return None
    print('transcription \'' + outputString + '\'')
    return outputString


rec = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
outputString = listen(rec, mic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(source, phrase_time_limit=5)` instead of `(source, timeout=5)`